# Split fasta files based on header

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, nested-loops, fasta

I have 1,500 fasta files with many protein fragments in them.  My goal is to separate these fragments into single files and to name these files something intuitive.

Here is an example of a fasta file that I have called plate9.H7.faa:

```
>39_fragment_4_295  (310978..311196)    1   None    hypothetical protein
MQTATKQETYDRTMKVTLAVKANGGSVTVQIQAGDNWITTDTFWKDGGYQLSIPPATIRYVPAAGAAFEVYA*
>39_fragment_4_296  (311193..312437)    1   VOG01158    REFSEQ hypothetical protein
MSLLVNPIPRRQPIRRGLGLLGDSFSGNCHTIAATAFGTEAYGYAGWIAARTGLFPSYVDNQGKLGDHTGQFLARLPACIASSTADLWLLLSRTNDSTTAGMSLADTKANVMKIVTAFLNTPGKYLIIGTGTPRFGSRALTGQALADAIAYKDWVLSYVSQFVPVVNIWDGFTEAMTVEGLHPNLLGAEFISSRVVPIITANFEFPGIPLPTDAGDIYSAIRPFGCLNANPLLAGTGGTLPAGVNAAAGSVLADGYKAVGSGLTGITTRWFKEPAAYGEAQCIELRGNMAAAGGYIYMQPTANVVQTNLAAGDVIEMVSAVEIMGSSRGILAWEAELTITKTVSGAASTFYYRSMDKYQEPFTMPASFSGALETQRGTIDLTETVITSRMGLYLAAGVPQDSTVKAAQFGIRKV*
>56_fragment_9_667  (768674..769846)    -1  K14059  int; integrase
MGRDGRGVRAVSDTSIEITFMYRGVRCRERITLKPSPTNLKKAEQHKAAIEHAISIGAFDYSVTFPGSPRAAKFAPEANRETVAGFLTRWLDGKKRHVSSSTFVGYRKLVELRLVPALGERMVVDLKRKDVRDWLSTLEVSNKTLSNIQSCLRSALNDAAEEELIEVNPLAGWTYSRKEAPAKDDDVDPFSPEEQQAVLAALNGQARNMMQFALWTGLRTSELVALDWGDIDWLREEVMVSRAMTQAAKGQAEVPKTAAGRRSVKLLRPAMEALKAQKAHTFLADAEVFQNPRTLQRWAGDEPIRKTMWVPAIKKAGVNYRRPYQTRHTYASMMLSAGEHPMWVAKQMGHSDWTMIARVYGRWMPYWDDIAGTKAVSQWAENAHESSDSK*
>56_fragment_9_668  (770054..770281)    -1  PF02599.16  Global regulator protein family
MLCLSRRVGESIVIGDNIKITVISGRDGQIRLGIDAPAELAVDRSEVRTAKLATPCGIGLKLRTVAESGARDDEG*
>56_fragment_9_669  (770485..770697)    1   None    hypothetical protein
MECTTTADEVYGPRNAKLGKRAVDGNIWSGTTMIFRIIDDRVYSMHEQYLGRLKYGMAMTDRGELIFIVR*
>56_fragment_9_670  (770705..771487)    -1  VOG00563    sp|Q05292|VG77_BPML5 Gene 77 protein
MSESTIDPKKLERAIRKIKHCLALSQSSNENEAATAMRQAQALMREYHLTETDVKVSDVGEVESSMSRAARRPLWDQQLSAVVATVFNVKALRYTHWCETKKNRVERAKFVGVSPAQHIALYAYETLLAKLSQARNAYVAGVRAGKFRSSYSAPTAGDHFAIAWVFAVESKLQQLVPRGEENTTPEYKGAGPGLVAVEAQHQALIDSYLADKQVGKARKVRGSELDLNAQIAGMLAGTKVDLHAGLANGAEHAQVLPASA*
```

So far I have been able to split the files into many files with this command:

```
for x in *.faa; do csplit -z $x '/>/' '{*}'; done
```

And then rename them according to their fragment in the header:

```
for file in xx*; do mv "$file" `head -1 "$file" | cut -d$'\t' -f 1`_$x.fasta; done
```

And then rename each file to not have the '>' from each file, along with assigning it the original filename:

```
for i in *.fasta; do mv $i `echo $i | cut -c 2-`; done
```

My problem is that this works on a single file (since there are temporary files in the directory I am doing it in that are temporarily called xx00, xx01, xx02, xx03, and so on..

I feel like my solution would be to loop through each fasta file and do all of these for loops in succession before starting the next fasta file, and I feel like that would have to be a nested for loop which I have never done myself.  Any guidance for what I could do would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will improve performance by using a tool that doesn't require files to be opened and closed all the time. Awk is an excellent choice for this.

It seems to me that similar results to what you have written could be achieved with:

```
$ awk '/^>/ { file=substr($1,2) ".fasta" } { print > file }' *.faa
```

Note that unless you `close()` a file, awk leaves it open until the awk process is done, so the solution above will append to common fragment names, should they appear in multiple input files.

If you have a very large number of these (tens of thousands), then `*.faa` might expand to too many files for your shell to handle on one command line. If that's the case, you could process things more slowly using `find`.

Comment: Thank you, I always forget about awk but this worked very nicely.  Do you have an idea of how I'd save each file as the original file name and then the fragment header name?  Right now your command only saves it as the fragment name.

Comment: I figured it out:  for i in *.faa; do awk '/^>/ { file=substr($1,2) ".fasta" } { print > file }' $i | rename fasta $i *.fasta; done

Comment: As I said in my answer, I would recommend against doing things in the for loop; you will have much better performance if you handle all your processing in the file itself. It is hard for me to gauge what your `rename` command is doing; there are several tools by that name in Linux, with different behaviour. If you could update your question with some examples of the output you're looking for (i.e. filenames), I would be happy to update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can print to outputs as defined in a variable.
Using your sample data above:

```
$: ls -l *.fasta
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 1124 Jun 21 08:56 tmp.fasta

$: for f in *.fasta; do 
     awk '/^>/ { sub(/^>/, "", $1); f=$1; next; } 
          { print >> f; close(f); }' "$f"
   done

$: grep . 56_*
56_fragment_9_667:MGRDGRGVRAVSDTSIEITFMYRGVRCRERITLKPSPTNLKKAEQHKAAIEHAISIGAFDYSVTFPGSPRAAKFAPEANRETVAGFLTRWLDGKKRHVSSSTFVGYRKLVELRLVPALGERMVVDLKRKDVRDWLSTLEVSNKTLSNIQSCLRSALNDAAEEELIEVNPLAGWTYSRKEAPAKDDDVDPFSPEEQQAVLAALNGQARNMMQFALWTGLRTSELVALDWGDIDWLREEVMVSRAMTQAAKGQAEVPKTAAGRRSVKLLRPAMEALKAQKAHTFLADAEVFQNPRTLQRWAGDEPIRKTMWVPAIKKAGVNYRRPYQTRHTYASMMLSAGEHPMWVAKQMGHSDWTMIARVYGRWMPYWDDIAGTKAVSQWAENAHESSDSK*
56_fragment_9_668:MLCLSRRVGESIVIGDNIKITVISGRDGQIRLGIDAPAELAVDRSEVRTAKLATPCGIGLKLRTVAESGARDDEG*
56_fragment_9_669:MECTTTADEVYGPRNAKLGKRAVDGNIWSGTTMIFRIIDDRVYSMHEQYLGRLKYGMAMTDRGELIFIVR*
56_fragment_9_670:MSESTIDPKKLERAIRKIKHCLALSQSSNENEAATAMRQAQALMREYHLTETDVKVSDVGEVESSMSRAARRPLWDQQLSAVVATVFNVKALRYTHWCETKKNRVERAKFVGVSPAQHIALYAYETLLAKLSQARNAYVAGVRAGKFRSSYSAPTAGDHFAIAWVFAVESKLQQLVPRGEENTTPEYKGAGPGLVAVEAQHQALIDSYLADKQVGKARKVRGSELDLNAQIAGMLAGTKVDLHAGLANGAEHAQVLPASA*
```

Does that help? You could also run the `awk`'s in background to process them in parallel, or use [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

Comment: Since there may be many thousands of output files, you'll need to `close(f)` after you print to it.

Comment: If you wanted to keep the header lines in the files as well, remove the `next`.

Comment: It is almost what I need.  I need the command to separate fragments based off the first number after the > and before 'fragment'.. I updated the question to be more reflective of what I need to happen.  Sorry I was not clear before

Comment: (So for my example file to separate into two new files since there is 39_fragment and 56_fragment)

Comment: I re-asked the question since I changed gears on what I needed to be done to my code.. Yesterday I believed that separating each fragment into different files would help but was not actually what I needed..

Comment: Here is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102153/split-one-file-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-pattern