# Split one file into multiple files based on a pattern

Tags: bash, file, split

I am trying to split one fasta file into several fasta files based on the number between each '>' and 'fragment'.  Some files only have one unique number between these and some have more than four.

I have 1,500 fasta files in this format.

Here is an example file: plate9.H6.phages.faa

```
>15_fragment_1_38   (32335..32991)  1   K01356  lexA; repressor LexA [EC:3.4.21.88]
MIRRMNKWYEVARQVMDTQQISQEEMAERMGVTPGAVGHWLNGKREPKIEVINRLLGELGLPILTTSIPWNEPGQQNVAPTEQPSRFYRYPVISWVEAGGWNEAVEPYPVGYSDTFELSDYKAKGRAFWLVVRGDSMTAPAGQSIPEGMLILVDTGIEPTPGKLVIAKLPESNEATFKKLVEDAGRYFLKPLNPAYPTIAISEECKLIGVIRQMTMRL*
>15_fragment_1_39   (33140..33397)  1   VOG04172    REFSEQ hypothetical protein
MQNLRPEASQHDAYLALAQRIQDLITSPKAQIEHQVLLVREPGESPVHWEQIVEQISEAEGINVTRNFENGSVNVSWYVESADAY*
>39_fragment_4_246  (275156..276328)    -1  K14059  int; integrase
MGRDGRGVRAVSDTSIEITFMYRGVRCRERITLKPSPTNLKKAEQHKAAIEHAISIGAFDYSVTFPGSPRAAKFAPEANRETVAGFLTRWLDGKKRHVSSSTFVGYRKLVELRLVPALGERMVVDLKRKDVRDWLSTLEVSNKTLSNIQSCLRSALNDAAEEELIEVNPLAGWTYSRKEAPAKDDDVDPFSPEEQQAVLAALNGQARNMMQFALWTGLRTSELVALDWGDIDWLREEVMVSRAMTQAAKGQAEVPKTAAGRRSVKLLRPAMEALKAQKAHTFLADAEVFQNPRTLQRWAGDEPIRKTMWVPAIKKAGVNYRRPYQTRHTYASMMLSAGEHPMWVAKQMGHSDWTMIARVYGRWMPYWDDIAGTKAVSQWAENAHESSDSK*
```

Here is what I want:
In this case, 2 files, one containing these sequences:

```
 >15_fragment_1_38  (32335..32991)  1   K01356  lexA; repressor LexA [EC:3.4.21.88]
    MIRRMNKWYEVARQVMDTQQISQEEMAERMGVTPGAVGHWLNGKREPKIEVINRLLGELGLPILTTSIPWNEPGQQNVAPTEQPSRFYRYPVISWVEAGGWNEAVEPYPVGYSDTFELSDYKAKGRAFWLVVRGDSMTAPAGQSIPEGMLILVDTGIEPTPGKLVIAKLPESNEATFKKLVEDAGRYFLKPLNPAYPTIAISEECKLIGVIRQMTMRL*
 >15_fragment_1_39  (33140..33397)  1   VOG04172    REFSEQ hypothetical protein
    MQNLRPEASQHDAYLALAQRIQDLITSPKAQIEHQVLLVREPGESPVHWEQIVEQISEAEGINVTRNFENGSVNVSWYVESADAY*
```

And another containing these sequences:

```
>39_fragment_4_246  (275156..276328)    -1  K14059  int; integrase
MGRDGRGVRAVSDTSIEITFMYRGVRCRERITLKPSPTNLKKAEQHKAAIEHAISIGAFDYSVTFPGSPRAAKFAPEANRETVAGFLTRWLDGKKRHVSSSTFVGYRKLVELRLVPALGERMVVDLKRKDVRDWLSTLEVSNKTLSNIQSCLRSALNDAAEEELIEVNPLAGWTYSRKEAPAKDDDVDPFSPEEQQAVLAALNGQARNMMQFALWTGLRTSELVALDWGDIDWLREEVMVSRAMTQAAKGQAEVPKTAAGRRSVKLLRPAMEALKAQKAHTFLADAEVFQNPRTLQRWAGDEPIRKTMWVPAIKKAGVNYRRPYQTRHTYASMMLSAGEHPMWVAKQMGHSDWTMIARVYGRWMPYWDDIAGTKAVSQWAENAHESSDSK*
```

The filenames should correspond to the original name (plate9.H6.phages.faa) along with the fragment number somewhere in the filename (so in this case either 15 or 39)

I have been able to split each fragment into its own file with this command, but this is not what I need.. It's the closest I have gotten to a solution.

```
for i in *.faa; do awk '/^>/ { file=substr($1,2) ".fasta" } { print > file }' $i | rename fasta $i *.fasta; done
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor adjustment of the same solution should work.
Have you read https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html ?

```
for f in *.faa; do 
  awk '/^>/ { file=substr($1,2,2) "." FILENAME  } 
       { print >> f; close(f); }' "$f"
done
```

Results:

```
$: grep . [0-9][0-9].*.faa
15.plate9.H6.phages.faa:>15_fragment_1_38   (32335..32991)  1   K01356  lexA; repressor LexA [EC:3.4.21.88]
15.plate9.H6.phages.faa:MIRRMNKWYEVARQVMDTQQISQEEMAERMGVTPGAVGHWLNGKREPKIEVINRLLGELGLPILTTSIPWNEPGQQNVAPTEQPSRFYRYPVISWVEAGGWNEAVEPYPVGYSDTFELSDYKAKGRAFWLVVRGDSMTAPAGQSIPEGMLILVDTGIEPTPGKLVIAKLPESNEATFKKLVEDAGRYFLKPLNPAYPTIAISEECKLIGVIRQMTMRL*
15.plate9.H6.phages.faa:>15_fragment_1_39   (33140..33397)  1   VOG04172    REFSEQ hypothetical protein
15.plate9.H6.phages.faa:MQNLRPEASQHDAYLALAQRIQDLITSPKAQIEHQVLLVREPGESPVHWEQIVEQISEAEGINVTRNFENGSVNVSWYVESADAY*
39.plate9.H6.phages.faa:>39_fragment_4_246  (275156..276328)    -1  K14059  int; integrase
39.plate9.H6.phages.faa:MGRDGRGVRAVSDTSIEITFMYRGVRCRERITLKPSPTNLKKAEQHKAAIEHAISIGAFDYSVTFPGSPRAAKFAPEANRETVAGFLTRWLDGKKRHVSSSTFVGYRKLVELRLVPALGERMVVDLKRKDVRDWLSTLEVSNKTLSNIQSCLRSALNDAAEEELIEVNPLAGWTYSRKEAPAKDDDVDPFSPEEQQAVLAALNGQARNMMQFALWTGLRTSELVALDWGDIDWLREEVMVSRAMTQAAKGQAEVPKTAAGRRSVKLLRPAMEALKAQKAHTFLADAEVFQNPRTLQRWAGDEPIRKTMWVPAIKKAGVNYRRPYQTRHTYASMMLSAGEHPMWVAKQMGHSDWTMIARVYGRWMPYWDDIAGTKAVSQWAENAHESSDSK*
```

Comment: I will have to read the String Functions tutorial you sent.  I have never used them and definitely need to learn about them.

Comment: Read the whole manual. Lots of good stuff in there - and you are quite welcome. :)